# Elementary row operation, how does the determinant show up here?

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I'm stuck on a rather simple exercise..

Given the equation

[image: Equation]

we should find k as such that the system has either one, infinite or no solution.

Written as a matrix this translates to:

[image: Elementary row operations]

I understand the first row operation, which just switches the rows, but how to arrive at the third? And why is the determinant showing up here?

[image: Determinant showing up here]

The teacher so far did not introduce determinants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To arrive at the third, we did $R_{2}\rightarrow k\cdot R_{1}+R_{2}$ where $R_{i}$ is row $i$ .

So the system is now equivalent to $$x-ky=0$$
$$(1-k^2)y=0$$

So two cases to consider:

1. If $k\neq\pm1$ then $y=0$, so second is satisfied and the first gives $x=0$ (trivial solution)
2. If $k=\pm1$, then the second is satisfied for any $y$ and from the first we obtain $x=ky$ for $y\in\mathbb R$ (and we have infinitely many solutions). Clearly if $y=0$ then we are back at the trivial solution.

Answer (score 1):

You take the first row times $k$ and add to the second row, so $1\cdot k + -k = 0$ and $-k \cdot k + 1 = 1-k^2$. That how you transform the matrix to row echelon form.